# Benchmarking IO action with Criterion

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, haskell-criterion

I want to know how long it takes my program to read a 12.9MB `.wav` file into memory. The function that reads a file into memory looks as follows:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString        as BS

getSamplesFromFileAsBS :: FilePath -> IO (BS.ByteString)
```

It takes the name of the file and returns the samples as a `ByteString`. It also performs some other validity checks on the data and ignores the header information. I read the `ByteString` of samples into memory using `ByteString.hGet`.

If I now benchmark this function with a 12.9MB file, using `Criterion`:

```
bencher :: FilePath -> IO ()
bencher fp = defaultMain [
  bench "Reading all the samples from a file." $ nfIO (getSamplesFromFileAsBS fp)
  ]
```

I get the following result:

```
benchmarking Reading all the samples from a file.
time                 3.617 ms   (3.520 ms .. 3.730 ms)
                     0.989 R²   (0.981 R² .. 0.994 R²)
mean                 3.760 ms   (3.662 ms .. 3.875 ms)
std dev              354.0 μs   (259.9 μs .. 552.5 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 62% (severely inflated)
```

It seems to load 12.9MB into memory in 3.617ms. This doesn't seem realistic since it indicates that my SSD can read 3+GB/s, which is not the case at all. What am I doing wrong?

I decided to try this another (more naive) way, by manually measuring the time difference:

```
runBenchmarks :: FilePath -> IO ()
runBenchmarks fp = do
  start <- getCurrentTime
  samplesBS <- getSamplesFromFileAsBS fp
  end <- samplesBS `deepseq` getCurrentTime
  print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

This gives me the following result: 0.023105s. This is realistic because it would mean my SSD can read at a speed of around 600MB/s. What is wrong with the `Criterion` result?

Comment: *"It seems to load 12.9MB into memory in 3.617ms. This doesn't seem realistic since it indicates that my SSD can read 3+MB/s, which is not the case at all."* That does not seem right. 12MB in 4ms would be 3GB/s, not 3MB/s.

Comment: @Zeta I'm sorry, you're right. It's a typo and I corrected it. 3GB/s is still not realistic for my SSD.

Comment: I'd say 3GB/s is realistic given a modern OS should cache the file in memory for you. This of course doesn't really explain the difference you get with Criterion.

Comment: Was the second benchmark ran on a cold OS FS cache? I believe criterion will run the benchmark many times and given sufficient free memory any subsequent runs apart from the first would use OS cache instead of re-reading from the disk, which could perhaps explain the difference. What measurements do you get when you invoke `runBenchmarks` twice / thrice?

Comment: @ppb The second benchmark was not ran on a cold OS FS cache. If I invokd `runBenchmarks` multiple times in succession, it gets faster. I average around 10ms now. The fastest I've seen is 8ms.  Maybe caching seems to be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the visual results of my `Criterion` benchmark by writing the output to a `html` file. I could clearly see that the first run took around 0.020s, whereas the rest (after caching) takes around 0.003s.

So I'm getting these results because of caching.